# How to do CRUD operations in Microsoft Dynamics CRM using html page

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365-sales

I want to do CRUD operations through HTML page without adding that page in Dynamics CRM's webresource.

Using C# we can connect with dynamics crm and can do get/add/edit/delete operations using CRM's dlls but I don't know the way of doing same from html page which is independent from CRM's webresource.

Can anybody please suggest me that is this possible or not and if yes then the way if there is any.

Comment: Why do you not want to use an HTML web resource? Do you need to access CRM from another web application?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen Yes.I want to access CRM from another web application.Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure which version you are using, as you tagged all versions (please, fix that, by the way) but assuming you are using Online version this is possible by using OAuth, there are already quite a few tutorials on the web how to do that

Comment: @PawelGradecki Yes,I am using Dynamics CRM 365 online.Can you please share the reference link for tutorial?

Comment: http://phuocle.net/crm/dynamics-365-online-s2s-authentication-full-explain.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform CRUD operations on Dynamics CRM 2016 and above using the [Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt593051.aspx).

You mention that your application will be independent of CRM, thus it will be on a separate domain. You will therefore need to register CRM in Azure and query the Web API with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt595797.aspx) is a good example from Microsoft demonstrating how to use [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) to connect an application with Dynamics CRM.